# exports not supported in browser

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am using [babel](https://babeljs.io/) for transpiling my code. I m getting below error :

> exports is not supported in the browser, you need a commonjs environment such as node.js/io.js, browserify/webpack etc

Code is :

```
export default function(){console.log("hello world")}
```

Comment: You need to transpile your code with babel before sending it to the browser. https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#babel_cli

Comment: i need to add options that which module to use while transpiling like commonJs or AMD. I realized this after posting my question.

Comment: @AbhijeetMishra: You may want to [answer your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) then if you could solve your problem.